# Settings.Deafult value change notification in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind a Label with Application Settings.

In Xaml i did the following

```
<Label  Content="{Binding Path=UserName, Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}}" />
```

Everything woks great when i change the value as following.

```
Settings.Default.UserName = "Test User";
```

But when i do something like

```
Settings.Default["UserName"] = "Test User";
```

The change does not reflect on the `Label`. The question here is why it does not trigger a notification change when used like dictionary. 
Or what do i need to do to trigger it in above mention scenario as well.

Comment: Just tried it myself, both lines of code cause UI to update. Are you using the `Settings` class that was auto-generated with your project?

Comment: Yes i am using the auto-generated `Settings` class.

Comment: I have the same behavior like Adi Lester says. In my generated Settings class property setter sets the value using indexer: this["UserName"] = value. Because of this both your varians must work.

Comment: Ahan then there must be something else... let me figure that out.

Comment: Problem is I am sharing Settings amongst different projects. So it was not the way Settings were set, rather from where which project settings were set. Posted a question for that, as it is totally a different problem so posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828344/share-application-settings-between-projects-and-use-data-binding-from-one-of-the).