# Share application settings between projects and use data binding from one of the project in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am working on an Application which has multiple projects in it. Lets just consider two for now `ProjectCore` and `ProjectUI`.

I need to share Application settings between these projects. What i did was, created Settings file at Solution level and add those settings as link in these projects (`Add Existing Item` -> `Add as Link`).

`ProjectUI` has some UIControls that are bind to `Settings.Default`'s different Settings. And `ProjectCore` sets value to `Settings.Default` as well.

Now if i use each project's Settings instance from Settings.Designer, they will be two different instances. So binding will not work if i set some value from `ProjectCore`.

`ProjectUI` depends on `ProjectCore`, so i can not just add Settings in ProjectUI and write a wrapper in `ProjectUI` and use that to set value from `ProjectCore`. This will create circular dependency.

Now how can i share and Settings file and keep the binding working for `ProjectUI`?

Comment: can't you implement setting in ProjectCore and give its reference to ProjectUI ??

Comment: What do you mean by reference here? Do you mean to Create it in `ProjectCore` and add it as a link in `ProjectUI?

Comment: If you meant `ProjectCore` reference then its already there, but settings is an internal class so can not use it directly.

Comment: have you define access modifier in settings to public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it may help you, I just create a sample in which i took two projects as you said, then i add setting to core project and change its access modifier to public and give its reference to UI, now i can access those setting in my UI project.

for. e.g.

```
test.Settings1.Default.SettingTest = "test";
```

here test is namespace, Setting1 is class and Default is static instance of Setting1 class.
SettingTest is my setting of type string. Though SettingTest is read-only i change its definition in desginer.cs to

```
public string SettingTest {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["SettingTest"]));
            }
            set {
                this["SettingTest"] = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont think it is wise to change access modifier of Auto-Generated class.

Comment: no public is required to access it in another assembly, by default it is internal, you can change it without any hesitation

Comment: yeah looks like the only solution for now